# Is method signature in PHP a MUST or SHOULD?

Tags: php, method-signature

I mean if it's called with `$request` which is not instance of `sfWebRequest` ,will it be fatal,or just a warning?

```
class jobActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->jobeet_job_list = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->execute();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Not yet,the framework will take days to learn.But I'm curious about the result

Comment: @unknown: But you could build a simple test case with just two simple classes like: `class A{} class B{public static function foo(A $obj){}} B::foo(new A()); B::foo("not A");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a catchable fatal error.

Here is an example:

```
class MyObj {}

function act(MyObj $o)
{
    echo "ok\n";
}

function handle_errors($errno, $str, $file, $line, $context)
{
    echo "Caught error " . $errno . "\n";
}

set_error_handler('handle_errors');

act(new stdClass());
/* Prints                                                                       
 *                                                                              
 * Caught error 4096                                                            
 * ok                                                                           
 */
```

If there wasn't a `set_error_handler` call the code will fail with an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to act() must be an instance of MyObj, 
instance of stdClass given, called in /home/test/t.php on line 16 and defined in
/home/test/t.php on line 4
```

Comment: What do you mean by `recoverable`?

Answer (score 5):

See the chapter on [TypeHinting in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

If `$request` is not a `sfWebRequest` instance *or* subclass thereof *or* implementing an [interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) of this name, the method will raise a [catchable fatal error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php). Script execution will terminate if the error is not handled.

Example

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C {}

function foo(A $obj) {}

foo(new A);
foo(new B);
foo(new C); // will raise an error and terminate script
```

With interfaces

```
interface A {}
class B implements A {}
class C {}

function foo(A $obj) {}

foo(new B);
foo(new C); // will raise an error and terminate script
```